# Отключение выделения текта в PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Всех приветствую.
Расскажите, и покажите как мне генерировать через python pdf файл, чтоб в конечном виде нельзя было что-то выделять/копировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перегони pdf в ps, а потом обратно в pdf.

Нужны утилиты pdftops и ps2pdf14.

```
pdftops -rasterize always '/home/eri/Загрузки/invoice-V023730587 (1).pdf'  '/home/eri/Загрузки/invoice-V023730587.ps'
ps2pdf  '/home/eri/Загрузки/invoice-V023730587.ps'
```

заменит все буквы на картинки и перегонит обратно в pdf

Comment: Интересно попробую